# Gradle --show-version

Tags: maven, gradle

What is the Gradle analog for Maven's `--show-version` option?

```
 -V,--show-version                      Display version information
                                        WITHOUT stopping build
```

Output includes Maven, Java and OS versions:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 23:22:22+0800)
Maven home: D:\Progs\maven\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

`-version` stops the build. Both lines below give the same result: version only

```
gradle build -version
gradle -version build
```

Comment: Try `gradle -version`

Comment: '-version' stops the build.

Comment: Don't understand? If You want gradle to display version use `gradle -version` command. It has nothing to do with `build`.

Comment: `--show-version` option is usually added in CI environment to add env details into log, as those enthronements are different. `--show-version` DOES NOT STOP BUILD. And you do not need modify 10, 100 etc of build configurations.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. In gradle there's no such switch. You can write custom task for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Gradle 5.0, `GradleVersion` is no longer accessible. Use

```
project.getGradle().getGradleVersion()
```

instead.

For example:

```
task printGradleVersion() {
    def gradleVersion = project.getGradle().getGradleVersion()
    println "Gradle version: $gradleVersion"
}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:gradle) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
gradle -v
```

This is the output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6
Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 2.6.32-042stab079.5 amd64
```

If you use it in CI environment, it doesn't stop the build.

Comment: `gradle -v build` just stops

Comment: I use it in trevis ci and it doesn't stop the build. What do you refear when you say that build stops?

Comment: I try it from console. It only shows version, no actual build is executed.

Comment: I added the '-v' option to a Jenkins build. It did stop the build after printing the version info.

Comment: Yeah not very useful info. In a CI environment and otherwise, `-v` stops the build.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Correct, nothing to add, but just note that the answer was written more than 5 years ago with gradle 1.10 and CI environments very different from the envs available today.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks, I didn't pay enough attention to the date!

Answer (score 7):

Just add this line at the very beginning of `build.gradle` script:

```
println GradleVersion.current().prettyPrint()
```

It won't stop the build and print all the required info (I hope so). Unfortunately haven't found docs for this class.

**EDIT**

Note for newer versions of Gradle: As prettyPrint is dropped from some gradle version, you can just add this line at the very beginning of build.gradle script:

```
println GradleVersion.current().getVersion() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getBuildTime() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getRevision() + GradleVersion.current().isSnapshot() ? " - is snapshot" : ""
```

Comment: prettyPrint is dropped from some gradle version. Currently you could something like println GradleVersion.current().getVersion() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getBuildTime() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getRevision() + GradleVersion.current().isSnapshot() ? " - is snapshot" : ""

Comment: Since Gradle 5.0 the internal class `GradleVersion` is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As prettyPrint is dropped from some gradle version, you can just add this line at the very beginning of build.gradle script:

```
println GradleVersion.current().getVersion() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getBuildTime() + " - " + GradleVersion.current().getRevision() + GradleVersion.current().isSnapshot() ? " - is snapshot" : ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Please input `gradle -v` on the terminal  and the output should look like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did using `org.gradle.internal`, that is definitely not future ready. And not as much info as in `gradle -version`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

println "Gradle "+gradle.gradleVersion
println org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()

repositories {
```

Comment: `org.gradle.internal` is dedicated not to be used by external users (can be changed for instance). As I said You can write custom task and most of info You need can pulled out from `System` class - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html