# Cannot find symbol error: Lombok 1.18.6 does not work with Gradle 5.2.1, JDK 10

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, lombok

Builds with Gradle 5.2.1 and Lombok 1.18.6 dependency are failing with JDK 10. It seems Lombok annotation are not being processed appropriately. I keep getting "cannot find symbol" error across various Java files in my source. Any thoughts on why this might be happening? I found that a defect has already been created: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1572

I am using:

Java JDK 10

Gradle 5.2.1

Lombok 1.18.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following work around for this issue using a plugin for processing Lombok annotation in compile time.

I had to perform the following steps in build.gradle:

1) Add `id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"` to plugins section.

2) Add `maven { url 'https://projectlombok.org/edge-releases' }` to repositories section.

3) Add the following to dependencies section:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:edge-SNAPSHOT'
apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:edge-SNAPSHOT'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18:6'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18:6'
```

4) Add a task:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.apt
}
```

This lets your build complete successfully.

Update 03/29/2019: This workaround also works with Gradle 5.3, Java JDK 10

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the fix or rather workaround isn't just using the snapshot repo (`edge-releases`) where this bug is already fixed?

Comment: This workaround does not fix this issue unfortunately. Updating IntelliJ to 2019.1 helped.

Comment: Can you please post or link to a full `bundle.gradle` file? I am getting build errors about method `apt()` not being defined.

Comment: annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18:6'
This was the only line that I needed to add.