# Apache-Pulsar schema doesn't have method builder()

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

I am trying to replicate the example [here](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/schema-understand/#complex-type), under **struct/SchemaDefinition**. I would like to define the schema for my messages into a class called `Davis` which is defined as follows:

```java
package com.example.streaming;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Davis {
    Timestamp timestamp;
    float temperature;
}
```

I have imported the annotations from the `Lombok project` and I don't know if this is correct but Pulsar's documentation is a bit poor here..
My producer class is something like this

```java
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.*;
import org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.schema.JSONSchema;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DavisProducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PulsarGetPropertyValues properties = new PulsarGetPropertyValues();
        properties.getPropValues();

        PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder()
                .serviceUrl(properties.getProperty("pulsar.service_url"))
                .authentication(
                        AuthenticationFactory.token(properties.getProperty("pulsar.token"))
                )
                .build();

        Producer<Davis> producer = client.newProducer(JSONSchema.of(Davis.class))
                .topic(properties.getProperty("pulsar.topic"))
                .create();

        // Send a message to the topic
        producer.newMessage().value(Davis.builder()
                .timestamp(sometimestamp)
                .temp_out((float) 18.5556)
                .build()).send();

        producer.close();

        client.close();

    }
}
```

The code won't compile because `Davis` doesn't have the method `builder()`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Lombok Project was not included as a `compileOnly` dependency in Gradle (v7.1).

Found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55227788/14314060

Answer (score 1):

I have another way to do this.   See if you like this style:

https://github.com/tspannhw/StreamingAnalyticsUsingFlinkSQL/blob/main/src/main/java/IoTProducer.java

https://github.com/tspannhw/StreamingAnalyticsUsingFlinkSQL/blob/main/src/main/java/IoTMessage.java

To get access to all the Pulsar people in one location, sign up for the summit

https://streamnative.io/en/blog/community/2021-09-07-speakers-announced-for-pulsar-virtual-summit-europe-2021/

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is brilliant! In your example, are you following the guidelines explained at https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-java/#avrobasestructschema-example?

Comment: I was using the StreamNative examples as my starter and that seems to work great.  https://github.com/streamnative/examples/tree/master/cloud/java/src/main/java/io/streamnative/examples/oauth2